# MySQL support for polish letter - ę

Tags: mysql, database

I'm having trouble making the letter ę appear in my mysql database.
I set all the tables to uf8_polish_ci but still the ę character changes into a ? character.
(I'm inputting all data directly into the database) Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Aleks

Comment: You should set the encoding from your table properly. Google by mysql encoding and [read this great article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use utf8_general_ci to support all kind of characters?

Define both the table and the fields as utf8_general_ci.

Also if you insert the fields using PHP or some other language, make sure the connection is set to utf-8 as well.

Answer (score 0):

try to declare **table fields**

(spróbuj na polach tekstowych tabeli zadeklarować - nie tylko na całej tabeli):

`nazwa` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT '0' **COLLATE 'utf8_polish_ci'**,